# When copying buttons from one workbook to another, avoid having assigned macro point to source workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I use this method to copy buttons from a template file to other files:

```
templateWbk.Sheets("C").Shapes("MCButton").Copy
instanceWbk.Sheets("C").Shapes("MCButton").Top = instanceWbk.Sheets("C").Range("U3").Top
instanceWbk.Sheets("C").Shapes("MCButton").Left = instanceWbk.Sheets("C").Range("U3").Left
```

I don't know if it is the best way to copy a button from one file to another, but it works.

I have a problem though. When copying buttons from one workbook to another, the buttons point to a macro in my source workbook. What is a good way to make them point to the same named macro in the target workbook instead?

To explain further, when I click on assing macro on the button in the target workbook I see the macro name:

```
'C:\SourceFilePath\SourceFileName.xls'!MacroName
```

but I only want to see:

```
MacroName
```

Comment: Facing same issue. original sheets have some button click code. And in destination workbook, on button click, it is referring code of original workbook. Let me know if you have got the solution

Answer (score 0):

Rather than copy buttons or other object/macros/sheets from your template workbook to another workbook, consider copying the entire workbook.  This will copy everything.

Then customize InstanceWbk.

Comment: Facing same issue. I am copying entire sheets. Original sheets have some button click code. And in destination workbook, on button click, it is referring code of original workbook.